# wireless transfer of data from raspberry pi 3 to pc using python

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I am doing my master thesis and one of the important things for me is to transfer the recordings of pressure and temperature from a patient simulator to a PC. From the sensors, the information is taken by the raspberry pi3. I am using raspberry pi3 because it has inbuilt wifi option. Now I have to transfer the data from the raspberry pi to the PC wirelessly using python programming. I am new to python and I have absolutely no idea how to do this. Could anyone help me with writing the code so that I could at least send some data from where I could adjust the bit rate and other things according to my requirements?

Comment: It's hard to recommend the best method without knowing the mechanism that is used for transferring the data. Is it WLAN (wifi), bluetooth, IR, 433.92MHz?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at sockets, a simple client - server communication is really easy to do :)
https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication

Comment: Thank you Sygmei...that helped me a lot.